# When should Pollard Rho be used as opposed to trial division?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, integers

How does one know which factorization algorithm to use on a given integer? More specifically, when should [Pollard Rho Brent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm) be used instead of simple trial division? Given the random nature of Pollard Rho Brent it's hard to know with certainty how long it will take to work (e.g. you could get lucky and pick  a starting value that quickly leads to a cycle).

Comment: Programs designed to factor "arbitrary" integers (for instance [yafu](https://sites.google.com/site/bbuhrow/home)) are usually designed to start with trial division to find small factors, then try Pollard and others up to some limit, then switch to more sophisticated algorithms like [ECM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic-curve_factorization), [SIQS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve) or [GNFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve). Chosing when to switch to a "higher" algorithm is part of the art of software crafting...

Comment: The answer is basically: when continuing with the lower level algorithm is not worth the time spent.

Comment: Pollard Rho is already much more efficient than trial division, if the smallest factor has, lets say $12$ or more digits. Even better in this case is the elliptic curve method (ECM). The Pollard Rho method is not guaranteed to find a nontrivial factor at all, if it does, the needed number of steps is roughly $\sqrt{p}$ , if $p$ is the smallest prime factor.